# OAuth2 response with client_id instead refresh_token

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have two example of oauth2 clients in php, one works and the other not, it return an error instead:

> ([error] => unauthorized [error_description] => An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext).

My question is, when it should a oauth2 server returns an access token response with client_id and when should it return a response with refresh_token?

My working request is:

```
string(130) "{"access_token":"b91f15ed-436f-470d-8d9e-bf245c5373ae","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":25209,"scope":"read","client_id":"tonr"}"
```

My not working request is:

```
string(126) "{"access_token": "eaa3c66ae1", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 31536000, "refresh_token": "69f9c2cb29", "scope": "user"}"
```

Since it just changes `client_id` and `refresh_token`, when should it come one and when should it come another?

Answer (score 0):

The refresh tokens are managed by the third party app you are using to get the `access_token`. That been said you can't directly request a refresh token.